# Sorting groups of lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Say I have this list:

```
sharpest
  tool
  in
the
  shed
im
  not
  the
```

How can I order alphabetically by the non-indented lines and preserve groups of lines? The above should become:

```
im
  not
  the
sharpest
  tool
  in
the
  shed
```

Similar questions exist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521803/how-to-sort-groups-of-lines) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310680/sorting-group-of-lines) but I can't seem to make them work for my example.

Hopeful ideas so far

- Maybe I could use `grep -n` somehow, as it gives me the line numbers? I was thinking to first get the line numbers, then order. I guess I'd somehow need to calculate a line range before ordering, and then from there fetch the range of lines somehow. Can't even think how to do this however!
- [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) ranges look promising too, but same deal; `sed 1,2p` and [further examples here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Range-Addresses.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `perl` is okay:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print sort split /\n\K(?=\S)/' ip.txt
im
  not
  the
sharpest
  tool
  in
the
  shed
```

- `-0777` slurp entire file, so solution not suitable if input is too big
- `split /\n\K(?=\S)/` gives array using newline character followed by non-whitespace character as split indication
- `sort` to sort the array

Comment: Nice answer! I personally needed the POSIX from anubhava but this is still so awesome

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `asort` function in a single `gnu awk` command:

```
awk '{if (/^[^[:blank:]]/) {k=$1; keys[++i]=k} else arr[k] = arr[k] $0 RS} 
END{n=asort(keys); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s\n%s", keys[i], arr[keys[i]]}' file
```

```
im
  not
  the
sharpest
  tool
  in
the
  shed
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/DQKHIO)

---

Alternative solution using `awk + sort`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if (/^[^[:blank:]]/) k=$1; else arr[k] = arr[k] $0 RS; next}
{printf "%s\n%s", $1, arr[$1]}' file <(grep '^[^[:blank:]]' file | sort)
```

```
im
  not
  the
sharpest
  tool
  in
the
  shed
```

Edit: POSIX compliancy:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'FNR==NR{if (/^[^[:blank:]]/) k=$1; else arr[k] = arr[k] $0 RS; next} {printf "%s\n%s", $1, arr[$1]}' file | 
  grep '^[![:blank:]]' file | 
  sort
```

Comment: Thank you for the POSIX! Only gave it to Sundeep as he was first

Comment: @NickBull imo you should choose answer which better suits you :) not based on who happened to see and answer the question first..

Comment: @Sundeep I didn't specify that when I should have, and (I hope) you can't read my mind! :) So yours is the first correct answer. Thank you both

Comment: @anubhava Actually just double-checking the first script and it doesn't seem to work! It only prints the nonintended phrases in order.

Comment: I have added a [working code demo](https://ideone.com/DQKHIO) in my answer for first awk command. As I mentioned it requires a `gnu awk`

Comment: @anubhava In fact scrap that comment. This works fine, I must've been doing something dumb.

Answer (score 1):

With single GNU **`awk`** command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" }
     /^[^[:space:]]+/{ k = $1; a[k]; next }
     { a[k] = (a[k]? a[k] ORS : "")$0 }
     END{ for(i in a) print i ORS a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
im
  not
  the
sharpest
  tool
  in
the
  shed
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` one-liner

```
$ awk '/^\w/{k=$1; a[k]=k; next} {a[k]=a[k] RS $0} END{ n=asorti(a,b); for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[b[i]] }' file
im
  not
  the
sharpest
  tool
  in
the
  shed
```